USB Sound Card not listed PLEASE help
First off I'm an Ubuntu noob and thanks for you're help!
I'm running ubuntu 22.04 on a Raspberry Pi5 and my USB sound card isn't listed under arecord -l
w6iwn@w6iwn-pi5:~$ arecord -l
arecord: device_list:277: no soundcards found...

I do see it listed in lsusb
w6iwn@w6iwn-pi5:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0424:2412 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) Hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 10c4:ea60 Silicon Labs CP210x UART Bridge
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0d8c:0012 C-Media Electronics, Inc. USB Audio Device
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
w6iwn@w6iwn-pi5
This what lsmod lists
w6iwn@w6iwn-pi5:~$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 98304  4
snd_seq_dummy          12288  0
snd_hrtimer            12288  1
qrtr                   45056  2
algif_hash             12288  1
algif_skcipher         12288  1
af_alg                 32768  6 algif_hash,algif_skcipher
bnep                   32768  2
8021q                  53248  0
garp                   20480  1 8021q
mrp                    20480  1 8021q
stp                    12288  1 garp
llc                    16384  2 stp,garp
hci_uart              167936  0
btqca                  24576  1 hci_uart
btrtl                  36864  1 hci_uart
btintel                53248  1 hci_uart
vc4                   479232  9
btbcm                  20480  1 hci_uart
snd_soc_hdmi_codec     24576  2
btsdio                 20480  0
aes_ce_blk             32768  4
bluetooth             954368  35 btrtl,btqca,btsdio,btintel,hci_uart,btbcm,bnep,rfcomm
aes_ce_cipher          12288  1 aes_ce_blk
joydev                 32768  0
drm_display_helper    225280  1 vc4
crct10dif_ce           12288  1
ecdh_generic           16384  2 bluetooth
polyval_ce             12288  0
cec                    90112  2 vc4,drm_display_helper
polyval_generic        12288  1 polyval_ce
ecc                    40960  1 ecdh_generic
snd_usb_audio         454656  1
drm_dma_helper         24576  2 vc4
ghash_ce               24576  0
brcmfmac_wcc           12288  0
snd_soc_core          372736  2 vc4,snd_soc_hdmi_codec
gf128mul               20480  2 polyval_generic,ghash_ce
snd_usbmidi_lib        45056  1 snd_usb_audio
binfmt_misc            24576  1
snd_compress           28672  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               12288  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
raspberrypi_hwmon      12288  0
sm4                    12288  0
snd_hwdep              24576  1 snd_usb_audio
sha2_ce                16384  0
sha256_arm64           24576  1 sha2_ce
sha1_ce                12288  0
snd_ump                40960  1 snd_usb_audio
input_leds             12288  0
cp210x                 40960  0
snd_pcm               184320  5 snd_usb_audio,snd_soc_hdmi_codec,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
usbserial              65536  1 cp210x
pwm_brcmstb            12288  0
snd_seq_midi           24576  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            49152  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_ump
brcmfmac              483328  1 brcmfmac_wcc
brcmutil               28672  1 brcmfmac
onboard_usb_hub        20480  0
snd_seq               118784  9 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_dummy
cfg80211             1159168  1 brcmfmac
rpivid_hevc            65536  0
snd_seq_device         16384  4 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_ump,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              49152  3 snd_seq,snd_hrtimer,snd_pcm
v3d                   131072  7
pisp_be                53248  0
v4l2_mem2mem           45056  1 rpivid_hevc
videobuf2_dma_contig    24576  2 pisp_be,rpivid_hevc
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_dma_contig
videobuf2_v4l2         32768  3 pisp_be,rpivid_hevc,v4l2_mem2mem
snd                   139264  18 snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hwdep,snd_usb_audio,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_soc_hdmi_codec,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_ump,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
rfkill                 40960  8 bluetooth,cfg80211
gpu_sched              61440  1 v3d
videodev              348160  4 pisp_be,videobuf2_v4l2,rpivid_hevc,v4l2_mem2mem
drm_shmem_helper       24576  1 v3d
pwm_fan                20480  0
videobuf2_common       81920  6 pisp_be,videobuf2_dma_contig,videobuf2_v4l2,rpivid_hevc,v4l2_mem2mem,videobuf2_memops
mc                     94208  7 videodev,snd_usb_audio,pisp_be,videobuf2_v4l2,videobuf2_common,rpivid_hevc,v4l2_mem2mem
rp1_adc                12288  0
raspberrypi_gpiomem    12288  0
pwm_rp1                12288  1
sch_fq_codel           24576  3
fuse                  163840  8
dm_mod                200704  0
dax                    49152  1 dm_mod
nfnetlink              20480  1
ip_tables              36864  0
x_tables               65536  1 ip_tables
autofs4                57344  2
btrfs                1794048  0
blake2b_generic        20480  0
xor                    12288  1 btrfs
xor_neon               16384  1 xor
raid6_pq              110592  1 btrfs
libcrc32c              12288  1 btrfs
hid_logitech_hidpp     61440  0
hid_logitech_dj        36864  0
hid_generic            12288  0
usbhid                 77824  2 hid_logitech_dj,hid_logitech_hidpp
xhci_plat_hcd          16384  0
spidev                 28672  0
dwc3                  159744  0
macb                   86016  0
ulpi                   20480  1 dwc3
phylink                73728  1 macb
i2c_designware_platform    12288  0
spi_dw_mmio            12288  0
i2c_designware_core    32768  1 i2c_designware_platform
spi_dw                 36864  1 spi_dw_mmio
nvme                   53248  2
nvme_core             176128  3 nvme
nvme_auth              28672  1 nvme_core
dwc2                  380928  0
rtc_rpi                12288  1
sdhci_brcmstb          28672  0
8250_bcm7271           32768  0
roles                  16384  2 dwc2,dwc3
udc_core               86016  2 dwc2,dwc3
gpio_brcmstb           24576  8
cqhci                  49152  1 sdhci_brcmstb
gpio_generic           24576  1 gpio_brcmstb
i2c_brcmstb            24576  0
reset_brcmstb          12288  2
spi_bcm2835            32768  0
reset_brcmstb_rescal    16384  1
gpio_keys              20480  0
phy_generic            20480  1
uio_pdrv_genirq        16384  0
nvmem_rmem             12288  0
uio                    32768  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
z3fold                 24576  32
zstd                   12288  8
w6iwn@w6iwn-pi5:~$ 

